# Finding jordan form and rational form of a $5x5$ matrix.

Tags: matrices

Consider  $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 2 & 0 &0 \\
    0 & 0& 0 & 6& 0\\
    0&0&0&0&12 \\
    0&0&0&0&0\\
 0&0&0&0&0
  \end{bmatrix}$$
Since the characteristic polynomial is $t^5$, the eigenvalues are $0$ so it suffices to find the null space of $A$ which is $\lbrace (t,x,0,0,0)\rbrace $ where $t,x \in \mathbb{R}$. I conclude that the Jordan form is   $[e_1,e_2,0,0,0]$. Am I on the right track? How can I find the rational form from here? Should I have found the rational form first?

Comment: I do not follow. This is obviously of rank $3$, so the Jordan form must have rank 3 as well.

Comment: I double-checked via wolfram that the null space is the set of elements $(t,x,0,0,0)$

Comment: oh, you meant the null space. I see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to check $A^2 \neq 0$ while $A^3=0$. So the minimum polynomial of $A$ is $t^3$. So you must have a Jordan block $J_3(0)$. Also, as mentioned in the comments, the Jordan matrix must have rank 3, so we must have $A$ is similar to Dg$[J_3(0),J_2(0)]$. Since over any field $\mathscr{F}$, the polynomial $t^5$ splits, the Jordan form and rational canonical form will be the same.

Comment: What is the notation $J_3(0)$? They are the same, but is my formula for the Jordan form correct?

Comment: \begin{equation} J_3(0)=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\\0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}.\end{equation} I have to admit I am not so sure what your notation indicates...is it a block diagonal form? then I would say it seems incorrect. Even if $e_1=(0,1,0,0,0)^T$ and $e_2=(0,0,1,0,0)^T$, then you are still missing the block $J_2(0)$.

Comment: Stop Hattingh on my notation ;). Just kidding, thank you for the clarification.

Comment: A pleasure! So in general $J_n(\lambda)$ is a square matrix of order (size) $n$ with $\lambda$ on the diagonal and $1's$ on the sub-diagonal (or super-diagonal).